# Получить список регионов в зависимости от страны через яндекс API

Tags: jquery, yandex-maps-api

Как получить список регионов с помощью яндекс API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ссылка на [документацию](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/dg/concepts/regions-docpage/) - модуль "регионы".

Пример с выводом в консоль:

```
ymaps.borders.load('RU').then(function (geojson) {
   console.log(geojson);
}, function (e) {
   console.log(e);
});
```

Comment: Ключ то нужен или нет, что то не пойму?

Comment: да, потребуется ключ "JS API и Геокодер". Ссылка на документацию в разделе JS API https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/borders.load-docpage/